# double Jumping In Unity 3d - GetAxis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was trying to implement a double jump in Unity, but I have a problem implementing it. I already have a normal jump, but the problem is with the second one.

I was trying to use

```
Input.GetButtonUp("Jump")
```

, but my player has problems with this second jump. In console I see that my player makes this jump but in real his not. Sometimes I need to press space like 30 times to make this second jump, even If I see in Console that he made it many times.

I was trying to implement it by using

```
jump = Input.GetAxisRaw("Jump");
```

but in this case, if we press space, we will receive 30 function calls before we jump, and the ground check is set to false.

```
public class PlayerBHV : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float horizontal;
    private float jump;
    public float speed = 1000f;
    public float jumpHeight = 50f;
    public float run = 1.5f;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public LayerMask WhatIsGround;
    public bool grounded;
    public bool doubleJump;

    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius ,WhatIsGround);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        IsGrounded();
        horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        jump = Input.GetAxisRaw("Jump");

        if (grounded && jump == 0)
        {
            doubleJump = false;
        }

        if (rb != null)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal, 0) * Time.fixedDeltaTime * speed * run;
            }

            if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal, 0) * Time.fixedDeltaTime * speed;
            }

            if (jump != 0 && grounded)
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal, jumpHeight);
                Debug.Log("skok");
            }

            if (jump != 0 && !doubleJump && !grounded)
            {
                    Debug.Log("tutaj");
                    rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal, jumpHeight);

                    doubleJump = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)` instead of `Input.GetAxisRaw("Jump")`. Also you should move `rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();` to the `Start` method, because there is no need to set rb every frame

Comment: Well your isgrounded function  return value isnt doing anything.   Dont get rb every fixed update. Its a waste of time only need it once.

Comment: Try to debug your `IsGrounded` method, `groundCheckRadius` can be the problem

Comment: @GeorgeKarlinzer I try this, but there is the same problem with the jump. About the ground check, I will try, but for now, it's working. 
There is a video about my problem where you can see what I mean about no jump after press space, even if we see that we are inside jump.. https://youtu.be/fwW3h1Pii3w

Comment: @MateuszJarecki just to clarify, your method will return the true or false that you expected. When returning the value of the assignment, you'll actually get the value of that assignment operation. It's a little obscure, but it does work. Your issue is in your logic further down in the Update. In fact, almost 3/4 of your Update should be in the FixedUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I overlooked something when answering this question meaning everything I written bellow is incorrect.

private bool IsGrounded()
{
return grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius ,WhatIsGround);
}

This is a pure method, meaning it does not change any data - only returns a value.

In:

```
void Update()
{
    IsGrounded();
```

You're executing IsGrounded() but ignoring the value it returns, you should be assigning your grounded boolean to the return value of IsGrounded(), like this:

```
void Update()
{
    grounded = IsGrounded();
```

Comment: Thanks for information. Yea that was my fault and I just change private bool IsGround() for 
`
private void IsGrounded()
    {
        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius ,WhatIsGround);
    }
`

Comment: Is `grounded` not set on the return line? It's a single equals, not double equals.

Comment: @Chuck That is correct, I overlooked the fact that he is assigning a variable and returning it in the same statement, this means everything I mentioned in my post is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what you're doing here. Right after your rigidbody null check, you **SET** the rb.velocity y component to zero.

```
if (rb != null)
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal, 0) * Time.fixedDeltaTime * speed * run;
    }

    if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
       rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal, 0) * Time.fixedDeltaTime * speed;
    }
```

So if you hit left shift, or don't hit left shift, vertical speed gets set to zero. Later you check about jumping, but it doesn't matter - next frame you set vertical speed to zero. I would get current velocity and set only the x component, like

```
var velocity = rb.velocity;
velocity.x = // your formula for speed
rb.velocity = velocity;
```